# jQuery Tools overlay too large for screen, cannot access lower content

Tags: jquery-tools

I've been using jQuery Tools' overlay for some time, but I don't know what to do when the browser window isn't large enough to accomodate the contents of the overlay.

Check out the [jQuery Tools example page](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/index.html) and see what I mean:

1. Click one of the images to make an overlay appear
2. Resize your window so that the entire overlay can't fit

This may seem like a simple problem with an easy solution (make your browser window larger), but I work on a website that caters to older people, whose monitors may be set at low resolutions.

Any idea what I can do, short of building my own javascript overlay utility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify the size of the overlay div in % so that it always fits on the screen.

```
overlay_div {
height: 60%;
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Max height solution without scroll:

```
overlay_div {
max-height: 95%;
}

overlay_div img {
max-height: 95%;
}
```

In script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("img[rel]").overlay({
  top: 25
  });
});
```